# Perfect forwarding with class template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, perfect-forwarding, template-argument-deduction

I would like to understand how deductions guides work with universal references and `std::forward`, in particular to create perfectly forwarding wrappers. The code below provides a code to experiment with a functor wrapper in two cases: one with an implicit deduction guide and one with an explicit deduction guide.

I have put a lot of `&&` and `std::forward` in comments, because I do not know where they are needed to achieve perfect forwarding. I would like to know where to put them, and where they are not needed.

```
// Case with not conversion constructor
template <class F>
struct functor1
{
    explicit constexpr functor1(F/*&&*/ f) 
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<F/*&&*/>)
    : _f(/*std::forward<F>(*/f/*)*/) 
    {}
    template <class... Args>
    constexpr operator()(Args&&... args) 
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_invocable_v<F/*&&*/, Args/*&&*/...>)
    {
        /*std::forward<F>(*/_f/*)*/(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    private: F/*&&*/ _f;
};

// Case with a conversion constructor
template <class F>
struct functor2
{
    template <class G>
    explicit constexpr functor2(G&& g) 
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<G/*&&*/, F/*&&*/>)
    : _f(/*std::forward<G>(*/g/*)*/) 
    {}
    template <class... Args>
    constexpr operator()(Args&&... args) 
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_invocable_v<F/*&&*/, Args/*&&*/...>)
    {
        /*std::forward<F>(*/_f/*)*/(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    private: F/*&&*/ _f;
};
template <class G>
functor2(G&&) -> functor2<G/*&&*/>;
```

EDIT: For the sake of simplicity, and because it is not the point of the question, in the preceding examples, we consider that `F` and `G` are function objects ie classes/structs with an `operator()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C++ standard defines the term *forwarding reference*. I suppose *universal reference* is used as a synonym for this term. [[temp.deduct.call]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.call#3)

> A *forwarding reference* is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a class template.

This concept only applies to template function argument or template constructor argument. In all other cases, `T&&` is a *rvalue reference*. The concept of *forwarding reference* is only usefull for template argument deduction. Let's consider that in the following examples, all the fonctions and constructors are called with an `int` argument (independently of its constness and value categories (lvalue/rvalue):

```
//possibilities of argument deduction, [cv] means any combination of "const" and "volatile": 
//  <"","const","volatile","const volatile">
template<class T> void f(T&);
  //4 possibilities: void f([cv] int&);

template<class T> void f(const T&);
  //2 possibilities: void f(const int&);
                   //void f(const volatile int&);

template<class T> void f(T&&);
  //Forwarding reference, 8 possibilities
            //void f([cv] int&);
            //void f([cv] int&&);

template<class T> void f(const T&&);
  //NOT a forwarding reference because of the const qualifier, 2 possibilities:
            //void f(const int&&);
            //void f(const volatile int&&);

template<class T>
struct S{
    template<class U>
    S(U&&);
      //Forwarding reference, 8 posibilities:
            //void S<X>([cv] int&);
            //void S<X>([cv] int&&);
      //no template argument deduction posible

    S(T&&);
      //NOT a forwarding reference, 1 possibility:
            //void S<X>(X&&);
      //Generated argument deduction:
         //template<class T> S(T&&) -> S<T>;
           //not a forwarding reference because T is a parameter of the template class; 
           //=> 4 possibilities: -> S<[cv] int&&>


    T&& a; //an rvalue reference if T is [cv] int or [cv] int&&,
           //an lvalue reference if T is [cv] int&;
           //This comes from reference colapsing rules: &+&=&; &&+&=&; &&+&&=&&       //(Nota: You may consider that a rvalue reference data member is probably a mistake)
 };

template<class U>
S(U&&) -> S<U&&>;
 //Forwarding reference, 8 possibilities:
 //   S<[cv] int&>;
 //   S<[cv] int&&>;
```

Using `std::forward` make sense only inside the body of a function or a constructor if the argument of `std::forward` can either be a rvalue reference or a lvalue reference, depending on template argument deduction and reference collapsing rules. If `std::forward`'s argument always results in a rvalue reference, `std::move` is prefered, and if it always results in a lvalue reference, nothing is prefered.