# Universal reference in variadic template class is treated as rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++17, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

I am trying to create variadic template that can get lvalues, rvalues and rvalue references as arguments. But it seems that `T&&` is treated as rvalue reference and wouldn't accept other types.

Am I missing something? I thought that `&&` is universal reference when used in templates.

```cpp
#include <string>

template <typename... T>
struct MyClass
{
    MyClass(T&&... values)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string string_value;
    
    //MyClass my_class(string_value); // class template argument deduction failed
    
    //MyClass<std::string> my_class(string_value); // cannot bind rvalue reference of type
    
    MyClass<std::string> my_class(std::move(string_value)); // OK
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7996ea4ab81e9b5d

Comment: *I thought that && is universal reference when used in templates.* Not quite. It is a universal reference only when its type is deduced. In `MyClass<std::string>`, nothing is deduced.

Comment: See [A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a class template. **This concept only applies to template function argument or template constructor argument. In all other cases, `T&&` is a rvalue reference.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986284/perfect-forwarding-with-class-template-argument-deduction)

Comment: See [When is a reference a forwarding reference, and when is it an rvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996187/when-is-a-reference-a-forwarding-reference-and-when-is-it-an-rvalue-reference).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, _It is a universal reference only when its type is deduced_ is a bit misleading imho. In `MyClass my_class(std::move(string_value))` `T&&` is deduced but still not a universal refererence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a universal/forwarding reference.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction):

> An rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter is not a forwarding reference if that parameter is a class template parameter:
>
> ````cpp
> template<class T>
> struct A
> {
>     template<class U>
>     A(T&&, U&&, int*); // #1: T&& is not a forwarding reference
>                        //     U&& is a forwarding reference
>  
>     A(T&&, int*);      // #2: T&& is not a forwarding reference
> };
> ```i
> ````